# how to make an array of objects that is not from a model into a ArrayDataProvider in Yii 1.1.14?

Tags: yii

so my variable contains an array of objects. each object is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => CustomAudienceBean Object
        (
            [limit:protected] => 
            [account_id:protected] => 2342354235235
            [approximate_account:protected] => 
            [data_source:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => SEED_BASED
                    [sub_type] => ENGAGEMENT_EVENT_USERS
                    [creation_params] => []
                )

            [type:protected] => 
            [sub_type:protected] => 
            [creation_params:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [delivery_status:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code] => 300
                    [description] => Audiences must include at least 20 people to be used for ads.
                )

            [code:protected] => 
            [description:protected] => 
            [external_event_source:protected] => 
            [id:protected] => 23423asdf23423tadf23
            [is_value_based:protected] => 
            [lookalike_audience_ids:protected] => 
            [lookalike_spec:protected] => stdClass Object
```

It's quite deep..
how to convert the array into a ArrayDataProvider in yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no out of the box way. Your `CustomAudienceBean` object's properties are protected, so you can't access them directly. You have to extend the class if there are no public methods.

You have 2 options,

1. Extend `CustomAudienceBean` class and define a method to return all the properties you need. Then iterate your dataset and build the array for `CArrayDataProvider`
2. Extend the `CArrayDataProvider` and feed your array of objects. Then inside your custom `ArrayDataProvider` you can extract the properties from `CustomAudienceBean` object

Comment: I've already solved my issued.. I extended the CDataProvider instead..then when I instantiate the my own new CDataProvider, I passed the bean object :D ..thanks anyway